# JavaScript show and hide select list

Tags: javascript, html

i have a selection list that contains for example countries :

```
<select id="Countries" name="Countries" onChange="check();">
   <option id="Countrie1" name="Countrie1">Country 1</option>
   <option id="Countrie2" name="Countrie2">Country 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to use Javascript to hide and show another select list (Teams list) depending from the selected element of the countries select list.

For example if Country 1 is selected then show the teams' selection list of Country 1

```
<select id="Teams_Country_1" name="Teams_Country_1">
   <option id="C1_Team1" name="C1_Team1">Team_1_Country_1</option>
   <option id="C1_Team2" name="C1_Team2">Team_2_Country_1</option>
</select>
```

if Country 2 is selected then hide the first one and show the second one in the same position.

```
<select id="Countries" name="Countries">
   <option id="C2_Team1" name="C2_Team1">Team_1_Country_2</option>
   <option id="C2_Team2" name="C2_Team2">Team_2_Country_2/option>
</select>
```

This is the code I am trying to modify to make it work.

```
function check() {
    var el = document.getElementById("Countries");
    var str = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
    if (str == "Countrie1") {
        showTeamsC1();
        hideTeamsC2();
    } else if (str == "Countrie2") {
        showTeamsC2();
        hideTeamsC1();
    }
}
function hideTeamsC1() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function showTeamsC1() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_1').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function hideTeamsC2() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function showTeamsC2() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

But this dosen't show the select list in the same position, and if I do it manually (try to use margin-top) it covers the other list.

Comment: Have you tried using display instead of visibility?

Comment: Last select should be named "Teams_Country_2". Also, in its option "C2_Team2" you missed opening the closing tag. Also work with values, not with the labels. E.g add attribute "value" to all your "option" tags and don't use spaces in it. Then define "str" like this: `var str = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;`. And use "===" operator. And start using jQuery. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display: none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`
[What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Visibility hidden is hiding the element but keep its space, but `display:none;` hide it without keeping its space.

So your code will be something like this:

```
function hideTeamsC1() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_1').style.display = 'none';
}
function showTeamsC1() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_1').style.display = 'block';
}
function hideTeamsC2() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_2').style.display = 'none';
}
function showTeamsC2() {
    document.getElementById('Teams_Country_2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: and then if I want to show it back. I need to use what ?

Comment: display: inline; or display:block;